# How do I expand $(y-1) = 3\sqrt{3}(x-\frac{\pi}{3})$ into y-intercept form?

Tags: calculus

I'm not sure what would happen if I multiplied $ 3\sqrt{3}(x-\frac{\pi}{3})$. I think it would be just  
$3x\sqrt{3} - \pi\sqrt{3}$

$\sqrt{3}(3x-\pi)$

Is this correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's currently in point-slope form.  In order to get it into y-intercept form, or more formally known as slope-intercept form, you need to expand the right hand side through distribution, and then add 1 to both sides to isolate the y.  Slope intercept for in the general form is 
$$y=mx+b$$
so now after those changes your line looks like
$$y=3\sqrt{3}x+(1-\sqrt{3}\pi)$$

Comment: You put $3\sqrt{3}x$. Would be putting it as $3x\sqrt{3}$ instead be incorrect?

Comment: I wouldn't call it incorrect, but you are putting it in form with the slope intercept formula, thus your slope comes first, and your y-intercept second.  Thus, since your actual slope is $3\sqrt{3}$, i would write it as $3\sqrt{3}x$, not $3x\sqrt{3}$.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean $y$-intercept form meaning to make $y$ the subject of the formula, then it is
\begin{align}
y-1 &= 3\sqrt 3 (x-\frac \pi 3)\\
y &= 3 \sqrt 3 (x- \frac \pi 3) +1
\end{align}

You are actually correct on the multiplication of $3 \sqrt 3$ where you said  it becomes $3 \sqrt 3 x - \sqrt 3 \pi$. However, if you intend to make it into the $y$ intercept form, remember that it is in the form $y = mx + c$. So there is no need to factorize once again. Keep it in the second form that you had.

\begin{align}
y-1 &= 3\sqrt 3 (x-\frac \pi 3)\\
y &= 3 \sqrt 3 \,x - \sqrt 3\, \pi +1
\end{align}

What can you see here? It is a straight line with gradient / slope $3 \sqrt 3 $ and $y$-intercept $1-\sqrt 3 \pi$.